# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, cryptography

I have these codes in Java where it is used for encryption and decryption for PRINCE. These are the codes for the Sbox and Sbox Inverse. Whenever I run the program, I get and error message of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at prince.SInv(prince.java:146)
    at prince.Encrypt(prince.java:485)
    at prince_analysis_main.main(prince_analysis_main.java:21)
```

I have implemented try and catch method by referring to http://mcnewton.org/blog/tag/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-5/ but it does not solve the problem.
Can I know if this error message is caused by the limited memory allocation or there is an error of the implementation?

```
public static long S(long x) {
            long[] sbox_8bits = new long[] { 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xB3, 0xB2, 0xBA, 0xBC,
                0xB9, 0xB1, 0xB6, 0xB7, 0xB8, 0xB0, 0xBE, 0xB5, 0xBD, 0xB4,
                0xFB, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xF2, 0xFA, 0xFC, 0xF9, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xF7,
                0xF8, 0xF0, 0xFE, 0xF5, 0xFD, 0xF4, 0x3B, 0x3F, 0x33, 0x32,
                0x3A, 0x3C, 0x39, 0x31, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x30, 0x3E, 0x35,
                0x3D, 0x34, 0x2B, 0x2F, 0x23, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x2C, 0x29, 0x21,
                0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x20, 0x2E, 0x25, 0x2D, 0x24, 0xAB, 0xAF,
                0xA3, 0xA2, 0xAA, 0xAC, 0xA9, 0xA1, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0xA8, 0xA0,
                0xAE, 0xA5, 0xAD, 0xA4, 0xCB, 0xCF, 0xC3, 0xC2, 0xCA, 0xCC,
                0xC9, 0xC1, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xC8, 0xC0, 0xCE, 0xC5, 0xCD, 0xC4,
                0x9B, 0x9F, 0x93, 0x92, 0x9A, 0x9C, 0x99, 0x91, 0x96, 0x97,
                0x98, 0x90, 0x9E, 0x95, 0x9D, 0x94, 0x1B, 0x1F, 0x13, 0x12,
                0x1A, 0x1C, 0x19, 0x11, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x10, 0x1E, 0x15,
                0x1D, 0x14, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x62, 0x6A, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x61,
                0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x60, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x7B, 0x7F,
                0x73, 0x72, 0x7A, 0x7C, 0x79, 0x71, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x70,
                0x7E, 0x75, 0x7D, 0x74, 0x8B, 0x8F, 0x83, 0x82, 0x8A, 0x8C,
                0x89, 0x81, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x80, 0x8E, 0x85, 0x8D, 0x84,
                0x0B, 0x0F, 0x03, 0x02, 0x0A, 0x0C, 0x09, 0x01, 0x06, 0x07,
                0x08, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x05, 0x0D, 0x04, 0xEB, 0xEF, 0xE3, 0xE2,
                0xEA, 0xEC, 0xE9, 0xE1, 0xE6, 0xE7, 0xE8, 0xE0, 0xEE, 0xE5,
                0xED, 0xE4, 0x5B, 0x5F, 0x53, 0x52, 0x5A, 0x5C, 0x59, 0x51,
                0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x50, 0x5E, 0x55, 0x5D, 0x54, 0xDB, 0xDF,
                0xD3, 0xD2, 0xDA, 0xDC, 0xD9, 0xD1, 0xD6, 0xD7, 0xD8, 0xD0,
                0xDE, 0xD5, 0xDD, 0xD4, 0x4B, 0x4F, 0x43, 0x42, 0x4A, 0x4C,
                0x49, 0x41, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x40, 0x4E, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x44 };   
            return (((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0xFF00000000000000l) >> 56)] << 56) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x00FF000000000000l) >> 48)] << 48) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x0000FF0000000000l) >> 40)] << 40) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x000000FF00000000l) >> 32)] << 32) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x00000000FF000000l) >> 24)] << 24) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x0000000000FF0000l) >> 16)] << 16) ^
                    ((long)sbox_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x000000000000FF00l) >>  8)] <<  8) ^
                    (long)sbox_8bits[(int) (x & 0x00000000000000FFl)]);
    }

    public static long SInv(long x) {
        long[] sboxInv_8bits = new long[] { 0xBB, 0xB7, 0xB3, 0xB2, 0xBF, 0xBD,
                0xB8, 0xB9, 0xBA, 0xB6, 0xB4, 0xB0, 0xB5, 0xBE, 0xBC, 0xB1,
                0x7B, 0x77, 0x73, 0x72, 0x7F, 0x7D, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x76,
                0x74, 0x70, 0x75, 0x7E, 0x7C, 0x71, 0x3B, 0x37, 0x33, 0x32,
                0x3F, 0x3D, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x36, 0x34, 0x30, 0x35, 0x3E,
                0x3C, 0x31, 0x2B, 0x27, 0x23, 0x22, 0x2F, 0x2D, 0x28, 0x29,
                0x2A, 0x26, 0x24, 0x20, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x2C, 0x21, 0xFB, 0xF7,
                0xF3, 0xF2, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0xF8, 0xF9, 0xFA, 0xF6, 0xF4, 0xF0,
                0xF5, 0xFE, 0xFC, 0xF1, 0xDB, 0xD7, 0xD3, 0xD2, 0xDF, 0xDD,
                0xD8, 0xD9, 0xDA, 0xD6, 0xD4, 0xD0, 0xD5, 0xDE, 0xDC, 0xD1,
                0x8B, 0x87, 0x83, 0x82, 0x8F, 0x8D, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8A, 0x86,
                0x84, 0x80, 0x85, 0x8E, 0x8C, 0x81, 0x9B, 0x97, 0x93, 0x92,
                0x9F, 0x9D, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9A, 0x96, 0x94, 0x90, 0x95, 0x9E,
                0x9C, 0x91, 0xAB, 0xA7, 0xA3, 0xA2, 0xAF, 0xAD, 0xA8, 0xA9,
                0xAA, 0xA6, 0xA4, 0xA0, 0xA5, 0xAE, 0xAC, 0xA1, 0x6B, 0x67,
                0x63, 0x62, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x66, 0x64, 0x60,
                0x65, 0x6E, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x4B, 0x47, 0x43, 0x42, 0x4F, 0x4D,
                0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x46, 0x44, 0x40, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x4C, 0x41,
                0x0B, 0x07, 0x03, 0x02, 0x0F, 0x0D, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x06,
                0x04, 0x00, 0x05, 0x0E, 0x0C, 0x01, 0x5B, 0x57, 0x53, 0x52,
                0x5F, 0x5D, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A, 0x56, 0x54, 0x50, 0x55, 0x5E,
                0x5C, 0x51, 0xEB, 0xE7, 0xE3, 0xE2, 0xEF, 0xED, 0xE8, 0xE9,
                0xEA, 0xE6, 0xE4, 0xE0, 0xE5, 0xEE, 0xEC, 0xE1, 0xCB, 0xC7,
                0xC3, 0xC2, 0xCF, 0xCD, 0xC8, 0xC9, 0xCA, 0xC6, 0xC4, 0xC0,
                0xC5, 0xCE, 0xCC, 0xC1, 0x1B, 0x17, 0x13, 0x12, 0x1F, 0x1D,
                0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x16, 0x14, 0x10, 0x15, 0x1E, 0x1C, 0x11 };
        return (((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0xFF00000000000000l) >> 56)] << 56) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x00FF000000000000l) >> 48)] << 48) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x0000FF0000000000l) >> 40)] << 40) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x000000FF00000000l) >> 32)] << 32) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x00000000FF000000l) >> 24)] << 24) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x0000000000FF0000l) >> 16)] << 16) ^
                  ((long)sboxInv_8bits[(int) ((x & 0x000000000000FF00l) >>  8)] <<  8) ^
                  (long)sboxInv_8bits[ (int) (x & 0x00000000000000FFl)]);
    }
```

Comment: This is not the full code. Where is your main method? On which line is the exception thrown. Please learn basic debugging. Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126145/java-formula-parsing-error) didn't do too well too. Btw, why did you create a new account?

Answer (score 0):

An Array index out of bounds exception means that you are trying to access
an index of the array that does not exist.

Example if your array has say 5 elements you are asking for the 6th element.

I'd look at what your SInv function calculate for your array indexes.